# PHP - File Uploads With Apostrophe issue

Tags: php, file-upload

I have tried `addslashes` & `str_replace(" ' ", " ", $_FILES['file']['name'])` to escape the apostrophe or remove it but neither makes any difference as I still get a 500 internal server error? Here is my code

```
<?php

$whitelist = array('application/pdf',
'application/vnd.ms-excel',
'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
'application/msword',
'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$uploadname = str_replace("'", "", $_FILES['file']['name']);
$uploadsize = str_replace("'", "", $_FILES['file']['size']);
$uploadtype = str_replace("'", "", $_FILES['file']['type']);
$uploadtemp = str_replace("'", "", $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

/*
$uploadname = addslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
$uploadsize = addslashes($_FILES['file']['size']);
$uploadtype = addslashes($_FILES['file']['type']);
$uploadtemp = addslashes($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
*/

if (empty($uploadname)) { 

$message = "<b> * No File Selected</b>"; }

else if ($uploadsize > 5000000) { 

$message = "<b> * 5MB Max Upload</b>"; }

else if (!in_array($uploadtype, $whitelist) && !empty($uploadname)) { 

$message = "<b> * PDF, Excel orWord Format Only</b>"; }

else {

define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/home/moo/suppliers/');

$ext = pathinfo($uploadname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file = ''.rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext.'';

move_uploaded_file($uploadtemp, UPLOAD_DIR.$code.'/pricelists/'.$file);

$message = "<b> * File Uploaded</b>"; } }

?>
```

Is my use of `str_replace` & `addslashes` functions correct in this case? Could this error be caused by anything else as my server error log is empty?

Comment: Does it work without the apostrophe?

Comment: What does the Error log say ?

Comment: It does work without apostrophe & the error log is blank

Comment: if you have Error 500, the log shouldn't be blank unless you disabled error logging. enable it and check it again

Comment: Here is what I got from the log - I assume it means that I don't have a 500 error page? [Tue Aug 19 15:16:08 2014] [error] [client 105.237.9.160] File does not exist: /home/jackspai/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://www.jackspaintcrm.co.za/promotions/add_promotions.php

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the apostrophe problem? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ext = pathinfo($upload, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

$upload is undefined. also use `elseif` instead of `else if`

Comment: The $upload thing was a typo here on stack not in my code sorry

Comment: "also use `elseif` instead of `else if`" - It's up to him whether to use `elseif` or `else if`, as both work the same. It's a matter of opinions...

Comment: elseif is way more optimal than else if.
it's a matter of intermediate compiled code that is later interpreted. elseif creates one block where else if creates 2.